# Split SQL insert or XML to 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I have a large sql insert like, (this is not large, it was an example)

```
INSERT INTO `NAMES` (`Name`, `DunkerID`, `Birthday`, `Lastname`) VALUES ('Jacob',  'Jacob18', '1965-01-05', Schulz');
```

But i want the insert `Birthday` and `Lastname` and their values into a different table, how can i do that?

And the XML in the title would be if i could split XML the same way, like

```
<Name>Jacob</Name>
<DunkerID>Jacob18</DunkerID>
<Birthday>1965-01-5</Birthday>
<Lastname>Schulz</Lastname>
```

The reason i need to do that is because i already codes like this with wrong tables just waiting to be inserted.

Comment: Just use two separate `INSERT` statements?

Comment: I know but they are already finished

Comment: I have like 600 of these that just ignore the table

Comment: Create a trigger to insert into the other table whenever you insert a row in NAMES